# how to put html component on top border create by <div> element

Tags: html

I want to create border around my form and also want to put some HTML component on top border line created by  around my form. Check sample form created by me and the Radio button overlapping on top border line.
Can you please guide me how to achieve similar type of output.

--- O home  O office ---------------------------------
|                                        ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***            |
|           Address:     |                                |           |
|                            |                                |           |
|                            |                                |           |
|                            |***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**|           |
|                            **__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**            |
|       Phone No:   |***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**               |         |
|                                                                        |
|---------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Looks like you are trying to achieve something similar to frames in VB6...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/fieldset) and [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/legend)

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><input type="radio" name="location"> home  <input type="radio" name="location"> office</legend>
    form elements
 </fieldset>
<form>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kbyC4/1/)

Comment: type=checkbox  he was asking radio buttons not checkboxes :(

Answer (score 1):

```
   <form>
     <fieldset>
      <legend><input type=radio> home  <input type=radio> office</legend>

    Address: <input type="text"><br>

    Phone No: <input type="tel" ><br>

     </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Fieldset` and `legend` tags in html